# Angular check if item is in Observable array with Rxjs operators

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a function that selects an offer, but I need to check whether this offer is in the Observable array of offers$ first.

```
selectOffer(offer) {
    this.offers$.subscribe(items => {
      items.forEach(item => {
        if (item === offer) {
          // if offer is in offers$, DO...
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

How could I transform this to work with Rxjs operators (pipe, map, filter etc..)

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now? Or you want to have an Observable that emits `true/false` based on whether the item is in the array?

Comment: We'll need more code. What do you expect the `selectOffer` to return? What kind of observable is `this.offer$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `find` operator

Emit the first item that passes predicate then complete.

```
selectOffer(offer) {
    this.offers$.pipe(find((item: any) => item === offer)).subscribe(items => {
        console.log("Offer is in the list")
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map` on observables

Try like this:

```
selectOffer(offer) {
  this.offers$.map(item => item.filter(x => x === offer));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying several options, this one seemed the most effective for my case:

```
this.offers$
      .pipe(
        map(items =>
          items ? items.filter((item: any) => item === offer) : null)
      )
      .subscribe(item => { /* DO */ });
```